# I am trying to use junit with my app on bluemix the build is successful locally but on bluemix it fails due to line coverage check

Tags: java, junit, ibm-cloud, cobertura

I have uploaded an app on bluemix and recently integrated junit, the coverage check is passed locally but on bluemix the coverage check/line coverage fails

Comment: The error message says your problem is on line 25.

Comment: @user2083765 : Are your referring to DevOps services ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's a devops question, I unchecked the cobertura generated report files and forgot to check the test case before commit. Silly me :/